# mysql query error using join statement

Tags: mysql, join

When i run the following query i get an error like "Column 'manager_id' in where clause is ambiguous" how to resolve it.

```
select * from employee 
join leave_details on leave_details.employee_id=employee.id 
inner join manager on (manager.id=leave_details.manager_id) 
where manager_id=4;
```

I am using this query to display the leave details of a particular employee whose manager_id is xxx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message means manager_id column exists in more than one table you've put into your FROM section. Prefix field name with the table name (e.g. "employee.manager_id" if you mean employee) - even when it is not necessary, it's a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You must qualify manager_id:

```
select *
from employee
join leave_details on leave_details.employee_id=employee.id
inner join manager on (manager.id=leave_details.manager_id)
where employee.manager_id=4;
```